# How can I tell if a phone is connected by wifi or has access to mobile internet via C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, network-programming, wifi

When the phone is in the local network it has ip `192.168.0.x` when it is outside wifi access it uses internet connection provided by mobile network(the internet accessed when you have sim inside the phone).

How to determine by C# which kind of connection is used at the time?

EDIT:

```
NetworkInterfaceInfo netInterfaceInfo = socket.GetCurrentNetworkInterface();
    var type = netInterfaceInfo.InterfaceType;
    var subType = netInterfaceInfo.InterfaceSubtype;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this method to check network states:

```
public static string GetNetStates()
{
    var info = Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
    switch (info)
    {
        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma:
            return "CDMA";
        case NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm:
            return "CSM";
        case NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211:
            return "WiFi";
        case NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet:
            return "Ethernet";
        case NetworkInterfaceType.None:
            return "None";
        default:
            return "Other";
    }   
}
```

Comment: I check it. I tried that but didn't know how to initialize socket:look at edit

Comment: we needn't to initialize socket, just use NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType, it's static.

Comment: Works great, now I try to add a notification to `NetowrkInterfaceType` so the event will be fired when it changes.  Thank you for help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617822/how-to-add-listener-to-the-property-already-defined-in-net