# How to add listener to the property already defined in .NET

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

I want to be notified when the `NetworkInterfaceType` will change from `NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm` to `NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211` and the other way around:

```
var info = Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;
```

**How to do so? I would like to add a listener which will listen for changes of that property.**

Tried that:

`System.ComponentModel.DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType, typeof(NetworkInterfaceType)).AddValueChanged(info, (s, e) => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fsajfopsajopfasjopfsaj"); });`

but this is not available in WP8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the NetworkAvailabilityChanged as follow:

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new EventHandler<NetworkNotificationEventArgs>(NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
```

see [NetworkAvailabilityChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.networkavailabilitychanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for full explanation

Comment: I handled that differently, but I will be back at this question next time I need that. Thank you.